# Liferay link-to-layout structure

Tags: seo, liferay, structure

I want to use inside a Liferay structure the link-to-layout field,

```
<dynamic-element name="linktopage" type="link_to_layout" index-type="" />
```

In the template I use href="$linktopage.getURL()"
the link is working properly but the page url is /web/12/13

**I need to have a SEO url with the page name.**
Anyone know how to do that using link-to-layout and velocity variable?

Tnx
Sabrina

Answer (score 5, accepted):

instead of `$linktopage.getURL()`, try `$linktopage.getFriendlyURL()`, this should give you the url with page names instead of layout ids.

Comment: Great!!! Only one note: $linktopage.getFriendlyUrl() (is case sensitive) 
Thanks a lot
Sabrina